# How to determine which java application uses network port in windows?

Tags: java, web-applications, path, port, classpath

Common utilities like currports or netstat /ano will give you the PID of the process that is using each port - i.e. just says ***java.exe*** is using it.
But how to find out which java app/class is using some port? (say which app/class from what path/classpath).

Are there any utilities for the purpose?

Answer (score 3):

From netstat you will get the PID. In order to see which Java application uses a port, you will have to look up the command line that started the process with that PID.

Under Windows 10, the Task Manager's Detail View can show the command line - just right click the table header, click on 'select columns', and add 'command line'.

In other Windows versions, you can download ProcessMonitor from Microsoft, which shows you all running processes in a table. Again, right click on the table header, click on 'select columns' and add 'command line'.